# How to access clicked variable in linkClicked function in Navbar.tsx file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

How to access clicked variable in linkClicked function in Navbar.tsx file from Home.tsx file to check IF?[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

try this  `onClick={()=>linkClicked(Link)}`

the function linkClicked accept a string value so you have to pass a string